# Rounding Text Field

Tags: javascript, adobe, rounding

I have a text box titled NetAmt  and another box titled TotalGrossValue
I need the amount from NetAmt to populate the box TotalGrossValue and round up to the next $100.00.  So if the amount in NetAmt is $421.00, I need it to round to $500.00

I tried Math.cell(NetAmt/100)*100  but I am guessing the NetAmt is incorrect or needs more to the script.

Comment: Should work. You spelled ceil wrong. Change cell to ceil

Answer (score 0):

You could use modulus (reminder) to get the rest, and check if the number already is rounded to 100 (rest equals 0), if not add 100 minus the rest.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way add 100 to your NetAmt value and substract the reminder from them. use the below code for better understanding.

```
const TotalGrossValue =  NetAmt % 100  === 0 ? NetAmt : NetAmt + 100 - NetAmt % 100
```